# Jquery animation not smooth in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation

I am working on a website, where I want to move a div down as the user scrolls.
Everything works fine in other browsers, but the animation is not smooth in IE - it looks like it performs the animation AFTER the scroll is done, not right away, which makes it seem really bad.
The animation is simple, I am just changing the divs ,,top,, property inside window scroll function:

```
jqCaptionText.stop().animate({top: (25 + wScroll * 0.15) + '%'}, 0);
```

I also tried not using the animate function but instead the css function, but the same effect occurs

```
jqCaptionText.css({top: (25 + wScroll * 0.15) + '%'});
```

Any advice is appreciated,
thanks

Comment: What particular version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: It occurs in all versions of IE (I tested Edge, 10, 9) ... Is it possible to somehow link a video to better demonstrate the problem ? if not I will make a jsfiddle tommorrow